# When Connecting to SQL Server using Talend Tool, Connection fail and Getting Error

Tags: talend

When Connecting to SQL Server using Talend Tool, Connection fail and Getting the following Error:

```
    Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name
```

and sometimes getting the following Error:

```
     Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.
     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Login timed out.
```

Can any one assist me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

When "Login timed out" Error Occured, You need to check Network details and set the correct network.
Then it's work fine.